# Combining js libraries like Vue/Angular with other javascript assets?

Tags: javascript, angular, vue.js

I want to understand fully how front-end javascript libraries like Vue and Angular can work with other libraries/assets. For example, If I was to download a website template that already contains other javascript, can I convert that into a Vue or Angular app? Or do the libraries conflict when a service like webpack compiles to code? IE if I'm making a vue app. Does ALL my javascript need to be in the form of Vue code or can I link to a CDN that has some javascript that changes the DOM etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this unless you're forced to, I would say. Certainly don't do it if you're starting from scratch. First pick a framework, then pick a project template for that framework. If you really really have to, you are talking about a micro frontend architecture, and there's more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48691775/how-to-merge-angular-and-vue-projects-together) and [here](https://micro-frontends.org/).